# Show Constraint type in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, constraints, bit

I am trying to use show function to print to the console value of **zer** or **one**, but I can not do it. Here is my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import Control.Arrow
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Function

class Eq a => Bits a where
    zer :: a
    one :: a

instance Bits Int where
    zer = 0
    one = 1

instance Bits Bool where
    zer = False
    one = True

instance Bits Char where
    zer = '0'
    one = '1'
```

I am trying to use function **show** to convert zer or one to the string.
So I tried it:

```
k = zer
show k
```

but I got this error

```
<interactive>:10:1: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘show’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance (Show k, Show a) => Show (M.Map k a)
          -- Defined in ‘containers-0.5.7.1:Data.Map.Base’
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 24 others
        ...plus 11 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: show zer
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = show zer
```

so i tried to create instance for show. So I added this to my code:

```
instance (Show a) => Show (Bits a) where
    show zer = "0"
    show one = "1"
```

But I got another error

```
main.hs:25:28: error:
    • Expected a type, but ‘Bits a’ has kind ‘Constraint’
    • In the first argument of ‘Show’, namely ‘Bits a’
      In the instance declaration for ‘Show (Bits a)’
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What `String` do you expect to get out of `show k`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to make a **class** an instance of a class, rather than making a **type** an instance of a class. Compare:

```
Show a => Show (Bits a) -- Invalid
```

to

```
Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Valid
```

where `Maybe` is a datatype whereas `Bits` is a class name.

---

I don't think it's possible to express "anything that has a `Bits` instance has a `Show` instance", because it can lead to **overlapping instances**: if you could define something like that, then when you use `show :: Int -> String` the compiler wouldn't know whether to use the Prelude's instance of `Show Int` or the `show` that would be defined by `Int` being an instance of `Bits`.

A messy workaround could be to enforce "the other direction": that every instance of `Bits` must be an instance of `Show`, which would allow you to use `a`'s `Show` instance rather than your own one:

```
class (Show a, Eq a) => Bits a where
    zer :: a
    one :: a

main = print (zer :: Int)
```

although this requires an explicit type signature to resolve the ambiguity in the type of `zer` at the call site.

Comment: Thanks man,  now I am trying to calculate length [zer, one, zer], but I get Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘zer’. I thought that it should work normally as calculating length of [undefined, undefined, undefined].

Comment: @lukaskiss Nope, any use of `zer` or `one` will need enough type constraints that the compiler can infer precisely what type is used: here you'll need eg. `[zer :: Int, one, zer]` or `[zer, one, zer] :: [Int]`. The type of `undefined` isn't ambiguous, it's well defined as `a`, which is why that example works: the type of `[zer, one, zer]` is `Bits a => [a]`, where `a` is ambiguous. New problems should be asked as new separate questions though.